# How to properly update state in react in hooks?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to push an item to an array in the state but it is not working.
Here is my code.

```
const [features, setFeatures] = useState([''])


const addFeature = (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();

    let featuresClone = features;
    featuresClone.push('');
    setFeatures(featuresClone);
    console.log(featuresClone, fetaures);
}
```

This is the function which updates the state. In the log here features is updated.
but, when I do a useEffect like this,

```
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(features)
},[features])
```

It will not log the features which means features is not updated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the prev state and update the state like below,

```
const addFeature = (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();

    setFeatures(prev => [...prev, '']);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't mutate state directly, do this instead:

```
const addFeature = (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();

    let featuresClone = [...features];
    featuresClone.push('');
    setFeatures(featuresClone);
    console.log(featuresClone, fetaures);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, Can you explain why my approach did not worked?

Comment: when you did ```let featuresClone = features;``` it actually does not creates a new array, its just creates a new reference to the original state, and in react mutating the state directly is not allowed. In the above answer, when we do ```let featuresClone = [...features];``` then the new array having the same element as that of ```features``` gets created which then can be used to set the state.

Answer (score 1):

Your featuresClone is not a clone but the same list, because unlike primitive integers lists are passed by reference and not by value.

use: `let featuresClone = [...features,''];` to clone it and add the value

so you can also avoid `featuresClone.push('');` since with [].push it might happen that you modify a list that has only been passed on by reference.